# Replace text/string with new line

Tags: shell-script, command-line, command

I have had a requirement where I need to move data to a new line based on a text:

```
Input
:61: 456 B66666 :61: 878 N78777 :61: 534533534 BNNN

Output
:61: 456 B66666
:61: 878 N78777
:61: 534533534 BNNN
```

So basically as soon as it encounters `:61:` it should move to a new line.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a very simple solution which works perfectly on your example:

```
sed 's/ :61:/\n:61:/g' < input_file
```

You may have to adapt it a little, especially if you don't always have a space before `:61:` in your input files.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @lgeorget's answer, this adds a newline before any ":61:" that is **not** at the beginning of the line:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!^)(?=:61:)/\n/g' file
```

Comment: `(?<!^)` is a negative look-behind assertion: the current location does not immediately follow the start of the line. `(?=:61:)` is a positive look-ahead assertion: the current location is immediately followed by the string ":61:". If both of those are true, replace this (zero-width) string with a newline.